# How to retain domain descriptions from selected features in database to new database?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have the following script that selects features from an enterprise database and then exports them to a new database. However, two columns in the database contain domains. How can I keep the descriptions of the domains in the new database that is created rather than the domain numbers?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r'\\path\'
stateFeature = r'\\test.shp'
parish = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
nameField = "PARISH"


arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output, parish)

arcpy.Delete_management('SelectionStateLayer')
arcpy.Delete_management('lyr')


arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(stateFeature, 'SelectionStateLayer', '"' +     
str(nameField) + '" = ' + "'" + str(parish) + "'")


for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    if arcpy.Exists('lyr'): 
        arcpy.Delete_management('lyr')


    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, 'lyr') 
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('lyr', "INTERSECT", 'SelectionStateLayer') 

    outname = fc.replace(".","_") 
    outpath = output + r'/' + parish + '.gdb' + r'\{0}'.format(outname))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('lyr', outpath)

arcpy.Delete_management('lyr')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [FeatureClassToFeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) tool will automatically bring the domains over IF the output workspace is a geodatabase.  This tool also supports a where clause so you can supply that instead of making a new feature layer with the selection.

Comment: I was actually able to get it working with just:

    env.transferDomains = True

Thanks for the help though!